# algorithm - How to sort a 0/1 array with 2n/3 comparisons?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures

In [Algorithm Design Manual](http://www.algorist.com/), there is such an excise

> 4-26 Consider the problem of sorting a sequence of n 0’s and 1’s using
>   comparisons. For each comparison of two values x and y, the algorithm
>   learns which of x < y, x = y, or x > y holds.
>
> (a)  Give an algorithm to sort in n − 1 comparisons in the worst case.
>   Show that your algorithm is optimal.
>
> (b)  Give an algorithm to sort in 2n/3 comparisons in the average case
>   (assuming each of the n inputs is 0 or 1 with equal probability). Show
>   that your algorithm is optimal.

For (a), I think it is fairly easy. I can choose a[n-1] as pivot, then do something like in quicksort partition, scan 0 to n - 2, find the middle point where left side is all 0 and right side is all 1, this take n - 1 comparisons.

But for (b), I can't get a clue. It says **"each of the n inputs is 0 or 1 with equal probability"**, so I guess I can assume the numbers of 0 and 1 equal? But how can I get a result which is related to 1/3? divide the whole array into 3 groups?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"0 or 1 with equal probability" is the condition for "average" case. Other cases may have worse timing.

Hint 1: 2/3 = 1/2 + 1/8 + 1/32 + 1/128 + ...

Hint 2: Consider the sequence as a sequence of pairs and compare the items in each pair. Half will return equal; half will not. Of the half that are unequal you know which item in the pair is 0 and which is 1, so those need no more comparisons.

Comment: thanks. But maybe I am just stupid, could you please give me a further hint? I thought in this way originally too, but just don't know how to arrange those segments of comparisons

Comment: Added second hint. I'm not trying to be coy -- I'm just guessing you'd rather figure as much as possible out for yourself.

Comment: Can you please elaborate this a little more. Why do we consider the sequence as sequence of pairs. Also what happens if a pair is equal?
We can also have n/2 equal pairs and zero unequal pairs if the array of 0s and 1s is already sorted and is of size n

Comment: @Sandy, looking at pairs turns out to be useful because the values are limited to two values (0 and 1) and so a Greater or Less result tells you exactly what each values is. For pairs that test Equal, they are paired up with other such pairs and the process recurs. On average n/4 pairs will compare Equal and after pairing those up we need n/8 more comparisons, which is the 1/8 above. And so on for further Equal results. With n/2 equal pairs, the second level has n/4 comparisons. That's the worst case -- the problem asks for average case.

Comment: @xan, Can you give another hint whether this can be done in-place with existing array?
At the moment the best solution I have come up with is to have another array where I can explicitly store if the element is 0 or 1 as I discover. Then I traverse through the pairs and for <'s and >'s I set the values in second array. For ='s I store the links in a tree. Then I traverse again and mark <'s and >'s again and for ='s I again store the dependencies in a tree and traverse again. When all is clear I go and swap.
But something tells me that there is a better approach. Can you please give a hint?

Answer (score 0):

No it means that at any position, you have the same chance (probability) of the input value being 0 or 1. this give you a first clue : ***your algorithm will be randomized.***

The runtime will depend on some random variable, and you need to take the expected value to obtain the ***average complexity case***. Note that in this case, you have to detail during complexity analysis, as they require a precise constant (`2/3n` rather than simply `O(n)`)

**Edit:**
***Hint***. In the sorted array (the one you get at the end), what is only thing which varies, knowing you have only 2 possible elements.

Comment: Could you please give me a more detailed way for how to do it? It is not my school home work, I am just self-learning the book. thanks

Comment: according to your hint: the media of the sorted array? or say, from a position, the value (0) starts to change to 1